# How to use Regex in Windows Tools to find something in a XML file?

Tags: xml

I have a big XML file (~20 MB) that contains among others such lines:

```
<BUR value="0.01" />
```

Now I want to find all lines where value is greater than 0.33. How can I do this in Windows?

Comment: Do you have any scripting languages installed? Python, Perl, Ruby...? Which version of Windows (might have PowerShell onboard...)?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker No script languages installed and Window Vista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm. Matching number ranges isn't regexes' strong suit.

A regex that would work on arbitrary precision floats (except for exponential notation) could look like this:

```
<BUR value="0*(?:[1-9]\d*\.\d*|0\.[4-9]\d*|0\.3[4-9]\d*|0\.33(?!0+")\d+)" />
```

In PowerShell, which comes with Windows Vista, you could iterate over all lines that contain a matching string like this:

```
$regex = [regex] '(?m)^.*<BUR value="0*(?:[1-9]\d*\.\d*|0\.[4-9]\d*|0\.3[4-9]\d*|0\.33(?!0+")\d+)" />.*$'
$matchdetails = $regex.Match($subject)
while ($matchdetails.Success) {
    # matched text: $matchdetails.Value
    $matchdetails = $matchdetails.NextMatch()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a Windows specific answer, but you can do this with
Perl's XML:Xpath library better and easier than using regex:

```
$ xpath blurtst.xml  '//BLUR[@value > "0.33"]'
Found 4 nodes:
-- NODE --
<BLUR value="0.40" />-- NODE --
<BLUR value="0.50" />-- NODE --
<BLUR value="0.34" />-- NODE --
<BLUR value="0.35" />
```